# texttt in metropolis-beamer is sometimes in italic - XeLaTex and pdfLaTex

Tags: beamer, xetex, pdftex, typewriter, beamer-metropolis

I'm using Overleaf and metropolis theme to create my presentation in `beamer` and there is something wrong with `\texttt`. When using `XeLaTex` for compilation, `\texttt` returns text in italic:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{metropolis}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Frame Title}
    \texttt{something}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

With `pdfLaTex` it is ok. Moreover, when using default theme (no longer metropolis) it is also OK.
What am I missing and how can I fix it?

Comment: it can happen. The theme uses font names and something xelatex simply finds the wrong one. Try to reset it with `\setmonofont{FiraMono-Regular.otf}` (after the theme). Or use lualatex instead of xelatex.

Comment: This works perfectly! Thank you very much :)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was solved in the comments

Comment: `\setmonofont[UprightFont=*-Regular,BoldFont=*-Medium]{FiraMono.otf}` may be helpful if you still want bold monospaced text (e.g., for syntax highlighting)